# Pass the S3 bucket path as a parameter to a Jupyter Notebook in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

I have been able to trigger a Jupyter Notebook to execute via a Lambda function using an event (an object created in an S3 bucket). The parameter for the Jupyter notebook is the S3 path, and I want to pass the S3 path as a parameter to the notebook automatically. Can this be achieved? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How are you triggering a notebook via lambda?

If you are using scheduled notebooks on Studio you can look at passing parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebook-auto-run-troubleshoot-override.html

You could also look at converting your notebook into a python script and running it in a Training or Processing Job. You can then expose parameters as either Environment variables (Processing/Training Job) or as Hyperparameters (Training Job)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Amazon S3 event notification to trigger the Lambda function. For option 1, I can use Studio to schedule notebook on demand or on a fixed schedule, but it can not be triggered by an S3 event. For option2, I have to use the Jupyter notebook. My current thought is to pass the ```event['detail']['object']['key']``` from the Lambda function output to Lifcycle configuration in SageMaker, but I need to figure out the details.

Comment: You can trigger a lambda function to kick off a SageMaker training job on an S3 event. You can then pass any information from the event to Environment variables when creating the Job in Lambda. Your script running in the Training Job can then ingest the environment variables

Comment: Let me give a try today and keep you posted. Many thanks!

Comment: how can I pass the event from the Lambda function to Environment variables?

Comment: When creating the Job in lambda you can set the Environment variables : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_training_job.html

Comment: @Mark Karp. Appreciate your input. I still want to stick to notebook instance since I need to use Jupyter Notebook pattern down the road. My current thought is we get retrieve the information from CloudWatch Log streams.